# Hydra gives different password each time (DVWA)

Tags: passwords, kali-linux, hydra, dvwa

I've looked up this issue and everyone's problem was they didn't have the failed login string. I do. Trying to get into DVWA.
Here's my command

hydra 10.0.250.143 -l admin -P P.txt http-get-form "/dvwa/vulnerabilities/brute/index.php:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^&Login=Login:Username and/or password incorrect.:H=Cookie: security=low; PHPSESSID=uuojn9pfsbuehh26eitbvh6k91"

I've tried all different combinations of GET, POST, using just failed login striong, using just PHPSESSIS, using both, trying different files, trying /dvwa/login.php with these credentials and vise versa. Sometimes it stops after 16 sometimes it goes for a few minutes. But no matter what, it gives a few same incorrect ones over and over. What's happening?!?
[image: example run]